# How to define CSS to remove cluttered HTML?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="item">What did you buy?</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   id="item" 
                   placeholder="Example thing">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to repeat this code several times on my site, one after another, but can't find how to define something in CSS that will allow me to simply have something like `<div class="itemThing"></div>` instead of copying and pasting it so many times.

Comment: Wait, you want to repeat the above HTML using a CSS class?! o.0 .... *That's not how CSS works, that's not how any of this works.*

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that in CSS; CSS is a styling language which means it's for aesthetic purposes.

You can do something like this in JavaScript to dynamically generate `<div>` tags

```
function createDiv(id, parent)
{
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = id;
    document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(elem);
}
```

This is also obtainable through PHP, something like this for example

```
$element = "<div id=";
$count = 10;
for($id=0; $id<$10; $id++) {
    echo $element."div".$id."></div>"; 
    //You can do a lot more here, labels, pictures, whatever, just make sure your tags match in the end
}
```